Using std::variant for constructor
Need some input on using std::variant for the constructor.
The top section explains why I have so man constructors. The review is really about the last bit of code at the bottom. BUT and comments appreciated.
So previously my class looked like this:
class Socket
{
    public:
        Socket(FileInfo const& fileInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes)
            : connection(std::make_unique<FileConnection>(fileInfo, blocking))
        {}
        Socket(PipeInfo const& pipeInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes)
            : connection(std::make_unique<PipeConnection>(pipeInfo, blocking))
        {}
        Socket(SocketInfo const& socketInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes)
            : connection(std::make_unique<SocketConnection>(socketInfo, blocking))
        {}
        Socket(SSocketInfo const& secureSocketInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes)
            : connection(std::make_unique<SSocketConnection>(secureSocketInfo, blocking))
        {}

        std::unique_ptr<Connection> connection;

        // API removed.
};

The types FileIno/PipeInfo/SocketInfoSSocketInfo were distinct enough that the compiler could auto work out the type based on the input prameters.
// Example Usage:

    Socket   fileSocket{{"fileName", FileMode::Read}};   // Creates FileInfo
    Socket   pipeSocket{{}};                             // Creates PipeInfo
    Socket   socketSocket{{"google.com", 80}};           // Creates SocketInfo
    Socket   secureSocket{{"google.com", 443, ctx}};     // Creates SSocketInfo

But from the code I have been writing recently I found it useful to return a variant that could be one of these initializer types to initialize the socket.
So I wanted to do this:
    Socket    socket{getSocketInitializer(argc, argv[])}; 

But because functions can only return one type. I changed the initializer to be a std::variant:
 using SocketInit = std::variant<FileInfo, PipeInfo, SocketInfo, SSocketInfo>;
 SocketInit getSocketInitializer(int argc, char* argv[]);

Then changed the class implementation to:
class Socket
{
    struct ConnectionInit
    {
        Blocking blocking;
        ConnectionInit(Blocking blocking)
            : blocking(blocking)
        {}
        std::unique_ptr<Connection>  operator()(FileInfo const& fileInfo)     {return std::make_unique<FileConnection>(fileInfo, blocking));}
        std::unique_ptr<Connection>  operator()(PipeInfo const& pipeInfo)     {return std::make_unique<PipeConnection>(pipeInfo, blocking));}
        std::unique_ptr<Connection>  operator()(SocketInfo const& socketInfo) {return std::make_unique<SocketConnection>(socketInfo, blocking));}
        std::unique_ptr<Connection>  operator()(SSocketInfo const& secureInfo){return std::make_unique<SSocketConnection>(secureInfo, blocking));}
    };
    public:
        Socket(SocketInit const& socketInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes)
            : connection{std::visit(ConnectionInit{blocking}, socketInfo)}
        {}

        std::unique_ptr<Connection> connection;

        // API removed.
};

This now allows the getSocketInitializer() pattern to work (which is very useful). But the original usage pattern (As in the example) no longer works as the compiler can not deduce the class (So I have to be specific about the Initializer class in these cases).
I like this usage (in the example). So now I am looking to add back the original constructors. This is the code I want reviewed. What are opinions on this set of constructors:
class Socket
{
    struct ConnectionInit
    {
        Blocking blocking;
        ConnectionInit(Blocking blocking)
            : blocking(blocking)
        {}
        std::unique_ptr<Connection>  operator()(FileInfo const& fileInfo)     {return std::make_unique<FileConnection>(fileInfo, blocking));}
        std::unique_ptr<Connection>  operator()(PipeInfo const& pipeInfo)     {return std::make_unique<PipeConnection>(pipeInfo, blocking));}
        std::unique_ptr<Connection>  operator()(SocketInfo const& socketInfo) {return std::make_unique<SocketConnection>(socketInfo, blocking));}
        std::unique_ptr<Connection>  operator()(SSocketInfo const& secureInfo){return std::make_unique<SSocketConnection>(secureInfo, blocking));}
    };
    public:
        Socket(SocketInit const& socketInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes)
            : connection{std::visit(ConnectionInit{blocking}, socketInfo)}
        {}

        // The original set of constructors.
        // But for clean code they call the Variant constructor above.
        Socket(FileInfo const& fileInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes):            Socket(SocketInit{fileInfo}, blocking){}
        Socket(PipeInfo const& pipeInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes):            Socket(SocketInit{pipeInfo}, blocking){}
        Socket(SocketInfo const& socketInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes):        Socket(SocketInit{socketInfo}, blocking){}
        Socket(SSocketInfo const& secureSocketInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes): Socket(SocketInit{secureSocketInfo}, blocking){}

        std::unique_ptr<Connection> connection;

        // API removed.
};


It's not a good idea
The problem of using a std::variant for the constructor is that it removes flexibility and forward-compatibility from your API. Consider adding a new info type. Now you have to either change the SocketInit alias and recompile everything that uses it, or add an overload to the constructor that takes the new info type as a parameter, defeating the whole purpose of using std::variant in the first place.
Apart from just providing lots of overloads of the constructor for each info type, there are two other options:

Use type erasure. There are various ways to do this, one simple way is to provide a base class with virtual functions. I'm guessing that's what Connection is anyway.
Make the constructor templated on the info type.

The latter is actually not too different from using a std::variant, it's just that you don't hardcode the list of info types:
class Socket
{
    struct ConnectionInit
    {
        …
    };

    public:
        template<typename InfoT>
        Socket(const InfoT& socketInfo, Blocking blocking = Blocking::Yes)
            : connection{ConnectionInit{blocking}(socketInfo)}
        {}

        std::unique_ptr<Connection> connection;
};

If you want to you can restrict the allowed types for InfoT by making a concept for it.
Have a look at I/O streams
The standard library already had to deal with this issue when handling streams. There are file streams, standard input/output streams, string streams, span streams and you can add your own stream types as well. A socket is just a slightly more advanced stream.
If you were to copy the design of the standard library, you'd have a base class (BasicSocket) and several derived classes (FileSocket, PipeSocket and so on). The base class provides the type-agnostic API, and it uses virtual functions and/or type-erasure to pass information to the derived classes. In particular, note how std::basic_istream has an operator>>() which is not virtual, but instead operates on the type-erased rdbuf.
The split between a base class and derived classes means the code constructing a stream can simply write:
auto fileSocket = FileSocket{"filename", FileMode::Read};

The type is explicit, and the constructor of each derived class is simple, without needing variants, templates or overloads.
After construction it can then be passed to any function which takes a BasicSocket& parameter, and/or stored in a std::unique_ptr<BasicSocket>.

This was what I was initally trying to do f you want to you can restrict the allowed types for InfoT by making a concept for it. but stumbled on the variant technique instead. The variant technique was easier as I don't as yet understand the concepts syntax. Working on it still. Will revisit.
